# Change ImageView image after Checking internet status

Tags: android, sdk

i want to change a imageview image after i check the Internet statues.
basic, i want to check if the Internet works if it does i want to show a certain image.

here my code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    // get Internet status
    isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();

    // check for Internet status
    if (isInternetPresent) {
        // Internet Connection is Present
        // make HTTP requests
        showAlertDialog(AndroidDetectInternetConnectionActivity.this, "Internet Connection", "You have internet connection", true);
    } else {
        // Internet connection is not present
        // Ask user to connect to Internet
        showAlertDialog(AndroidDetectInternetConnectionActivity.this, "No Internet Connection", "You don't have internet connection.", false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am assume that you have knowledge of checking internet in Android.

in oncreate use this:

```
imagev = (ImageView)findviewbyid(R.id.imageview);
```

onbutton click:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

                // get Internet status
                isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();

                // check for Internet status
                if (isInternetPresent) {
                    // Internet Connection is Present
                    // make HTTP requests
                    showAlertDialog(AndroidDetectInternetConnectionActivity.this, "Internet Connection",
                            "You have internet connection", true);
                              imagev.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.withinternet));

                } else {
                    // Internet connection is not present
                    // Ask user to connect to Internet
                    showAlertDialog(AndroidDetectInternetConnectionActivity.this, "No Internet Connection",
                            "You don't have internet connection.", false);
                 imagev.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.nointernet));
                }
```

Comment: when put in the oncreate code it gives me a error on the assignment

Comment: what type of error you got?? force to close?? or anything else?

Comment: its ok i actually got it fixed

Answer (score 0):

Use below method to check internet is available or not

```
public static boolean isOnline(Activity context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

by setting below permission in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

then check like below

```
if(isOnline())
    img.setImageResource();
else
    img.setImageResource();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for changing image of `ImageView`.

```
 your_ImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_image_name);
```